# datasource.error microsoft sql:invalid column name 'generated_always_type' Erro code: 2146232060

Tags: sql, excel

Suddenly getting  below error

```
datasource.error microsoft sql:invalid column name 'generated_always_type'
```

[image]

when trying to execute the excel report connected to SQL. Till yesterday the reports are working well.

We couldn’t find the column with name “generated_always_type” in the database database.

[image]

Comment: Please confirm whether your data source exists and specify this data source to provide Stack Overflow users with more debugging details to assist you

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, for me what solved it was changing the conditions for the pulled data, i had a condition "when column = value" where the value is dynamic from a cell, i changed the condition to "column like '%value%'" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem updating the office version